# HTML Javascript How to redirect to 2 child pages with framed page

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

This is driving me crazy.  I know it must be easy, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

My `index.html` page is a framed page (don't ask---I inherited it and there are way too many child pages to deal with to fix it).

Anyway, frame1 is `menu.htm` and frame2 is `main.htm`.  You click on the menu and frame2 changes to whatever.  In my case to cabin pages on various lakes.

I killed off a page showing up in frame2 and I'm trying to redirect it to another.

The page I killed off is `/cabinslbj/index.htm` so I want a redirect back to `index.htm` with `menu.htm` in frame1 and `cabins.htm` (from the same folder as `index.htm` is in) to frame2.

I was thinking of something like...

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"
content="0;url=http://www.highlandlakes.com/index.html
frame1=menu.htm&frame2=main.htm" />
```

but I can't find the syntax anywhere...or does it need so javascript or a php page?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: html is not "programmable". you can stuff whatever query parameters onto a .html url you want, but they're utterly irrelevant to html. you'd need JS code in the `index.html` to parse out those query parameters and do something.

Comment: I don't know why it's removing part of the refresh tag:  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=  but that should be before the http://www. high...yadda, yadda, yadda

Comment: you didn't indent your code, so the html in it is being treated as part of your message and RENDERED, instead of being changed into `&lt;meta....` for display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy with a bit of javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.nuquery.com/v1m0/nuquery.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ready( function() {
        window.frames['frame1'].src = $._GET[ 'frame1' ];
        window.frames['frame2'].src = $._GET[ 'frame2' ];
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to set the frames on the init load of the page via query params or if you're trying a page in one frame to update another frame so hopefully this will be enough info to solve your problems.

First off you can get to the query params in javascript via

```
window.location.search
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

using a helper function like can ease the pain of getting to the query params.

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

to get to the frames of a page you'll

```
window.frames
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames

so using the help function above you could do something like

```
window.frames[1].location = getParameterByName('frame2');
```

and if you wanted to get have the page in frame1 change the page in frame2 you'll need to grab it's parent object and traverse back down.

```
window.parent.frames[1].location = 'anotherPage.html'
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent

Comment: Sooo...what exactly would the code on /cabinlbj/index.htm look like to redirect to the main page index.html with frame1 going to lakesect.htm and frame2 going to cabins.htm ?  I'm not understanding how to plug in the code above.  I'm  a guy who has been out of programming for a while.  I'm taking over my dad's old websites so he can retire and I'm trying to jazz them up.  Thanks for your help!  @Blake